# Consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection Rabbit MQ and Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, window, celery

I have created a small Flask app in which I want to carry out a task in Celery with the help of RabbitMQ.

I have installed and created the user in my Windows 10 system, but whenever I try to connect to RabbitMQ from my Flask app by running the following command, I get the error I have posted below.

```
celery -A  __init__.celery  worker -P solo  --loglevel INFO
```

My __init.py:

```
from Util import make_celery
from flask import Flask
app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'] ='rpc://' #{"broker_url":"", "result_backend":""}
app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']  ='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost'
celery = make_celery(app)
app_ctx = app.app_context()
app_ctx.push()
```

Uitl.py:

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

Error log:

```
[2023-05-20 17:41:00,805: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 514, in channel
    return self.channels[channel_id]
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 332, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 37, in start
    self.sync(c)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 41, in sync
    replies = self.send_hello(c)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 54, in send_hello
    replies = inspect.hello(c.hostname, our_revoked._data) or {}
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 389, in hello
    return self._request('hello', from_node=from_node, revoked=revoked)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 106, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 741, in broadcast
    return self.mailbox(conn)._broadcast(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\pidbox.py", line 328, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 898, in default_channel
    self._default_channel = self.channel()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 281, in channel
    chan = self.transport.create_channel(self.connection)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 166, in create_channel
    return connection.channel()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 517, in channel
    channel.open()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 448, in open
    return self.send_method(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 79, in send_method
    return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 99, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 530, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 294, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 627, in _read
    s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
[2023-05-20 17:41:00,808: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:367: CPendingDeprecationWarning:

In Celery 5.1 we introduced an optional breaking change which
on connection loss cancels all currently executed tasks with late acknowledgement enabled.
These tasks cannot be acknowledged as the connection is gone, and the tasks are automatically redelivered back to the queue.
You can enable this behavior using the worker_cancel_long_running_tasks_on_connection_loss setting.
In Celery 5.1 it is set to False by default. The setting will be set to True by default in Celery 6.0.

  warnings.warn(CANCEL_TASKS_BY_DEFAULT, CPendingDeprecationWarning)

[2023-05-20 17:41:00,869: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://myuser:**@127.0.0.1:5672/myvhost
[2023-05-20 17:41:00,931: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-05-20 17:41:00,932: WARNING/MainProcess] consumer: Connection to broker lost. Trying to re-establish the connection...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 514, in channel
    return self.channels[channel_id]
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py", line 332, in start
    blueprint.start(self)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bootsteps.py", line 116, in start
    step.start(parent)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 37, in start
    self.sync(c)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 41, in sync
    replies = self.send_hello(c)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\mingle.py", line 54, in send_hello
    replies = inspect.hello(c.hostname, our_revoked._data) or {}
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 389, in hello
    return self._request('hello', from_node=from_node, revoked=revoked)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 106, in _request
    return self._prepare(self.app.control.broadcast(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\control.py", line 741, in broadcast
    return self.mailbox(conn)._broadcast(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\pidbox.py", line 328, in _broadcast
    chan = channel or self.connection.default_channel
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 898, in default_channel
    self._default_channel = self.channel()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 281, in channel
    chan = self.transport.create_channel(self.connection)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 166, in create_channel
    return connection.channel()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 517, in channel
    channel.open()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\channel.py", line 448, in open
    return self.send_method(
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 79, in send_method
    return self.wait(wait, returns_tuple=returns_tuple)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 99, in wait
    self.connection.drain_events(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 525, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 530, in blocking_read
    frame = self.transport.read_frame()
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 294, in read_frame
    frame_header = read(7, True)
  File "C:\Hoonuit.Source\PersonalCode\MahaveerTrading\venv\lib\site-packages\amqp\transport.py", line 627, in _read
    s = recv(n - len(rbuf))
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```